# Show another button when using "commitEditingStyle" in a UITableView datasource

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to show an "Edit" button below the default "Delete" button that shows up with a swipe gesture on a cell when you implement "commitEditingStyle" on the table's datasource.

Is this possible by only implementing "commitEditingStyle" or will i have to implement my own way of showing the buttons on the cells? And if it is, how would i handle the commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to implement your own way of showing buttons on `UITableViewCells` by customizing the `UITableViewCells`.

As far as your requirement is concerned, I dont think its a good idea to show the "edit" button below the "delete" button, as accommodating both buttons vertically one-by-one may disappoint the user to make desired touch actions.

I mean to say, user may want to touch edit, but due to successive placing of custom edit/delete buttons, delete button may get clicked which is dangerous & not acceptable too. Of course,it will cause user to take proper care every-time making any of the edits.

Comment: You're right, below was a bad idea. Thanks for pointing that out.